# No wine menu after staging installation

Tags: 14.04, wine, menu

**My Ubuntu is 14.04LTS**
I've recently installed winehq-staging (I had winehq-devel before and I had Wine menu) and my Wine menu disappeared.
I've tried alacarte, and my menu shows up there, even all shortcuts are there, the menu is ENABLED **but it still won't show up!**

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, rebuild Wine menu
   `$ export WINEPREFIX=~/.wine; find $WINEPREFIX/drive_c/ -name "*.lnk" -exec wine winemenubuilder '{}' \;`
2. Run Alacarte (menu editor), click on Wine menu, and add any launcher to this cateogry.
3. You may or may not have to log off and log in again.